# Leaflet:: how to check if layerGroup has already layer added or not?

Tags: leaflet

i am using Leaflet Draw Plugin. i have created a Layergroup then i am adding Polygon, polyline and circle to it using addLayer Method. but i want to check is Layer already added to it or not?

Comment: If I understood you well you need the method `LayerGroup#hasLayer`. http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `L.LayerGroup.each()` function to iterate through each layer contained in a LayerGroup. See [L.LayerGroupAPI](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup).

```
DrawLayerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    alert(layer);
});
```

Alternatively, but slightly more of a hack, You can access the `_layers` property directly. `DrawLayerGroup._layers` will return an object containing references to each layer contained in that layer group.